# Using NSRegularExpression to extract URLs on the iPhone

Tags: objective-c, regex, nsstring, nsarray, nsregularexpression

I'm using the following code on my iPhone app, taken from [here](http://remarkablepixels.com/blog/2011/1/13/regular-expressions-on-ios-nsregularexpression.html?lastPage=true#comment17182355) to extract all URLs from striped .html code.

I'm only being able to extract the first URL, but I need an array containing **all** URLs. My NSArray isn't returning NSStrings for each URL, but the objects descriptions only.

How do I make my `arrayOfAllMatches` return all URLs, as NSStrings?

```
-(NSArray *)stripOutHttp:(NSString *)httpLine {

// Setup an NSError object to catch any failures
NSError *error = NULL;  

// create the NSRegularExpression object and initialize it with a pattern
// the pattern will match any http or https url, with option case insensitive

NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"http?://([-\\w\\.]+)+(:\\d+)?(/([\\w/_\\.]*(\\?\\S+)?)?)?" options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:&error];

// create an NSRange object using our regex object for the first match in the string httpline
NSRange rangeOfFirstMatch = [regex rangeOfFirstMatchInString:httpLine options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [httpLine length])];

NSArray *arrayOfAllMatches = [regex matchesInString:httpLine options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [httpLine length])];

// check that our NSRange object is not equal to range of NSNotFound
if (!NSEqualRanges(rangeOfFirstMatch, NSMakeRange(NSNotFound, 0))) {
    // Since we know that we found a match, get the substring from the parent string by using our NSRange object

    NSString *substringForFirstMatch = [httpLine substringWithRange:rangeOfFirstMatch];

    NSLog(@"Extracted URL: %@",substringForFirstMatch);
    NSLog(@"All Extracted URLs: %@",arrayOfAllMatches);

    // return all matching url strings
    return arrayOfAllMatches;
}

return NULL;
```

}

Here is my NSLog output:

```
Extracted URL: http://example.com/myplayer    
All Extracted URLs: (
    "<NSExtendedRegularExpressionCheckingResult: 0x106ddb0>{728, 53}{<NSRegularExpression: 0x106bc30> http?://([-\\w\\.]+)+(:\\d+)?(/([\\w/_\\.]*(\\?\\S+)?)?)? 0x1}",
    "<NSExtendedRegularExpressionCheckingResult: 0x106ddf0>{956, 66}{<NSRegularExpression: 0x106bc30> http?://([-\\w\\.]+)+(:\\d+)?(/([\\w/_\\.]*(\\?\\S+)?)?)? 0x1}",
    "<NSExtendedRegularExpressionCheckingResult: 0x106de30>{1046, 63}{<NSRegularExpression: 0x106bc30> http?://([-\\w\\.]+)+(:\\d+)?(/([\\w/_\\.]*(\\?\\S+)?)?)? 0x1}",
    "<NSExtendedRegularExpressionCheckingResult: 0x106de70>{1129, 67}{<NSRegularExpression: 0x106bc30> http?://([-\\w\\.]+)+(:\\d+)?(/([\\w/_\\.]*(\\?\\S+)?)?)? 0x1}"
)
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The method `matchesInString:options:range:` returns an array of `NSTextCheckingResult` objects.  You can use fast enumeration to iterate through the array, pull out the substring of each match from your original string, and add the substring to a new array.

```
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"http?://([-\\w\\.]+)+(:\\d+)?(/([\\w/_\\.]*(\\?\\S+)?)?)?" options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:&error];

NSArray *arrayOfAllMatches = [regex matchesInString:httpLine options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [httpLine length])];

NSMutableArray *arrayOfURLs = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

for (NSTextCheckingResult *match in arrayOfAllMatches) {    
    NSString* substringForMatch = [httpLine substringWithRange:match.range];
    NSLog(@"Extracted URL: %@",substringForMatch);

    [arrayOfURLs addObject:substringForMatch];
}

// return non-mutable version of the array
return [NSArray arrayWithArray:arrayOfURLs];
```

Comment: Beautiful! Worked like a charm! Thanks a lot jonkroll!

Comment: Works awesomely! Is It possible to get the title from after the > to <. like if the url is <a href="http://www.google.com">Google</a> you could get "Google"?

Answer (score 14):

Try NSDataDetector

```
NSDataDetector *linkDetector = [NSDataDetector dataDetectorWithTypes:NSTextCheckingTypeLink error:nil];
NSArray *matches = [linkDetector matchesInString:text options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [text length])];
```

Answer (score 8):

With `NSDataDetector` using Swift :

```
let types: NSTextCheckingType = .Link
var error : NSError?

let detector = NSDataDetector(types: types.rawValue, error: &error)        
var matches = detector!.matchesInString(text, options: nil, range: NSMakeRange(0, count(text)))

for match in matches {
   println(match.URL!)
}
```

> **Using Swift 2.0:**

```
let text = "http://www.google.com. http://www.bla.com"
let types: NSTextCheckingType = .Link

let detector = try? NSDataDetector(types: types.rawValue)

guard let detect = detector else {
   return
}

let matches = detect.matchesInString(text, options: .ReportCompletion, range: NSMakeRange(0, text.characters.count))

for match in matches {
   print(match.URL!)
}
```

> **Using Swift 3.0**

```
let text = "http://www.google.com. http://www.bla.com"
let types: NSTextCheckingResult.CheckingType = .link

let detector = try? NSDataDetector(types: types.rawValue)

let matches = detector?.matches(in: text, options: .reportCompletion, range: NSMakeRange(0, text.characters.count))

for match in matches! {
   print(match.url!)
}
```

Comment: fantastic answer. Simple example with all versions. +1

Comment: I don't think you need the . reportCompletion option since your not using enumerateMatches(in:options:range:using:)

Answer (score 6):

to get all links from a given string

```
NSRegularExpression *expression = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"(?i)\\b((?:[a-z][\\w-]+:(?:/{1,3}|[a-z0-9%])|www\\d{0,3}[.]|[a-z0-9.\\-]+[.][a-z]{2,4}/)(?:[^\\s()<>]+|\\(([^\\s()<>]+|(\\([^\\s()<>]+\\)))*\\))+(?:\\(([^\\s()<>]+|(\\([^\\s()<>]+\\)))*\\)|[^\\s`!()\\[\\]{};:'\".,<>?«»“”‘’]))" options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:NULL];
NSString *someString = @"www.facebook.com/link/index.php This is a sample www.google.com of a http://abc.com/efg.php?EFAei687e3EsA sentence with a URL within it.";

NSArray *matches = [expression matchesInString:someString options:NSMatchingCompleted range:NSMakeRange(0, someString.length)];
for (NSTextCheckingResult *result in matches) {
        NSString *url = [someString substringWithRange:result.range];
        NSLog(@"found url:%@", url);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I found myself so nauseated by the complexity of this simple operation ("match ALL the substrings") that I made a little library I am humbly calling [Unsuck](https://github.com/alexch/unsuck) which adds some sanity to `NSRegularExpression` in the form of `from` and `allMatches` methods. Here's how you'd use them:

```
NSRegularExpression *re = [NSRegularExpression from: @"(?i)\\b(https?://.*)\\b"]; // or whatever your favorite regex is; Hossam's seems pretty good
NSArray *matches = [re allMatches:httpLine];
```

Please [check out the unsuck source code on github](https://github.com/alexch/unsuck) and tell me all the things I did wrong :-)

Note that `(?i)` makes it case insensitive so you don't need to specify `NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive`.

Comment: That's totally awesome! Thanks for sharing your library, Alex!