# NSRegularExpression for get link in ios

Tags: ios, regex, hyperlink, nsregularexpression

How to write `NSRegularExpression`s to extract https links like these:

```
<br><img src=\"https://www.memberize.net/clubportal/images/gui/calicon_openpublic.gif\" border=\"0\">
```

Comment: you can visit this url for your answer
http://stackoverflow.com/a/9587987/1349201

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using NSRegularExpression to extract URLs on the iPhone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9587458/using-nsregularexpression-to-extract-urls-on-the-iphone)