# Adding images to uitextview at various locations dynamically

Tags: ios, uitextview, emoji

HI SO Developers and members,

I am developing an IOS app and i am integrating data from respective Web application to my application ,those pretty good web application developers are implementing emojies in chat serrvice by their own custom images such as .png. so i am getting the conversation messages like (message + .png image path )and these paths are at various locations in the text and at multiple times.so i have to display the .png images in the UITextview is this practically possible to do so,any suggestions are highly appreciated and thanks a lot for your time for this.

Input: HI!(some path of image as string)good morning(some path of image as string)its really a worth seeking

Output: HI()good morning() its really a worth seeking

Note:assume () this is a png image that i should show as emoji.

Answer (score 2):

To identify the substrings that need to be replaced by images you could use a regular expression. Ray Wenderlich provides a decent tutorial on regex in iOS ([swift](http://www.raywenderlich.com/86205/nsregularexpression-swift-tutorial) or [objective-c](http://www.raywenderlich.com/30288/nsregularexpression-tutorial-and-cheat-sheet)). For an SO example of regex extracting URLs from a string, which may be similar to what you need to implement, see: [Using NSRegularExpression to extract URLs on the iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9587458/using-nsregularexpression-to-extract-urls-on-the-iphone).

You could then loop through the matches in order to build up your message containing images. How you build up your message with the images depends on how you plan to access the images.

If you don't wish to download and store the images, either on the device or in memory, then an alternative solution to the `UITextView` would be to add the appropriate html tags to your message string (namely `img src`) and use a `UIWebView` ([docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIWebView_Class/)). E.g.

```
let exampleMessageString = "Text before image http://www.androidicons.com/assets/images/ai-mdpi-black/ic_action_achievement.png text in between images http://www.androidicons.com/assets/images/ai-mdpi-black/ic_action_armchair.png text after images"
let htmlMessageString = convertMessageStringToHtml(exampleMessageString)
// where convertMessageStringToHtml implements your regex and returns something like:
// Text before image <img src=\"http://www.androidicons.com/assets/images/ai-mdpi-black/ic_action_achievement.png\" /> text in between images <img src=\"http://www.androidicons.com/assets/images/ai-mdpi-black/ic_action_armchair.png\" /> text after images

let webView = UIWebView(frame: CGRectMake(x, y, width, height))
webView.loadHTMLString(htmlMessageString, baseURL: nil)
```

A `WebView` may not offer you the level of control you desire however. In which case you can use an attributed string ([docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/NSAttributedString_UIKit_Additions/index.html)) to display the message with images in your `UITextView`. You could still loop through your regex in the same way, but instead of building a html string you'd create attributed strings. There are plenty of examples of how to use attributed strings in other SO answers:

[iOS 7 TextKit - How to insert images inline with text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20930462/ios-7-textkit-how-to-insert-images-inline-with-text/20930656#20930656)

[How to add image and text in UITextView in IOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24010035/how-to-add-image-and-text-in-uitextview-in-ios)

If you need some help downloading images see: [iOS download and save image inside app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6238139/ios-download-and-save-image-inside-app)

Comment: Thanks for your time peteR and provided links as well.I have seen and are seeming worth.But here in my case i am not sure of how many such png images and where they present in the message is unimaginable.its totally depends on the user.like HI <image path> How are you <image path> and on and on .That image path could be anywhere in the message and any times.moreover there are multiple image paths that gives a way to multiple images,that i need to display as fairly as showing emojis in a text message.I hope you understand the issue here and i wait     for your response.Nice to meet you peter

Comment: I'd just be speculating from here sorry, as I don't fully understand the problem you're having. Would you be able to edit your question to provide more details like: a real example message, mocked up desired output, how you're retrieving the images, and some code of what you've tried so far.

Comment: HI Peter! I tried to attach the image but its not allowing me as i have no enough reputations.i will find some alternate and let you know the things better soon.Thanks for you timely responses

Comment: Don't worry about the mockup, I see what you're trying to do, thanks. What's the format of the image path though? Is it a url and you have to download the image? Is it a local file path for an image you've already downloaded or have access to? Is there anything in the message string that identifies some substring as an image path?

Comment: that path is the url of the image that i have to download Peter.if it make sense i can also store those images locally in my project if they could help me instead of downloading from web every time for every message.But how to identify those paths and set that appropriate image with out missing the location in the message.I mean that how to replace that path with the appropriate image

Comment: It sounds like you're stuck at identifying the image paths within the message string. In which case you could use a regular expression. I've edited my answer to provide some links to some relevant information (as well as an alternative to a UITextView). However, I'm definitely not an expert on regex, so if this is indeed the part where you're having problems, and the links don't help you, you may want to create a new SO question specifically targeting it.

Comment: Thankyou Peter,I will try with the above mentioned code and by seeing those tutorials.Thanks for all the way for your responses and proper guidance.

Comment: Not a problem. Good luck