# NSPredicate with NSDictionary, NSArray, JSON & HTML data

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, nsarray, nspredicate

I would like to fetch specific data in **JSON** data with **NSPredicate**. I don't know when I'm wrong, My *NSLog arrayBDD* works without NSPredicate...

Here is my code :

```
NSData *dataBDD = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:urlBDD];
NSDictionary *dicoBDD = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:dataBDD options:kNilOptions error:nil];
NSArray *arrayBDD = [[dicoBDD objectForKey:@"post"] objectForKey:@"content"];
NSLog(@"%@", arrayBDD);
NSPredicate *Predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF beginswith[c] '<a href='http://www.bundoransurfco.com/wp-content/uploads/'"];
NSArray *arrayPictures = [arrayBDD filteredArrayUsingPredicate:Predicate];
NSLog(@"%@", arrayPictures);

NSInteger count = [arrayPictures count];
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++){}
NSLog(@"%zd", count);
if (count == 0) {
    NSLog(@"0");
}
else if (count!=0){
    if (count==1){
        NSLog(@"1");
    }
    if (count==2){
        NSLog(@"2");
    }
    if (count==3){
        NSLog(@"3");
    }

    else{
        NSLog(@"too much");
    }
}
```

My ArrayBDD is :

```
<p><strong style="font-size: 13px;">5th March</strong></p>
<p>Swell is 3 foot to 4 foot at the peak and cross shore. Streedagh is worth a look for those wanting a beachie</p>
<p><span id="more-113"></span></p>
<p>High tide: 1811 4.0m    <span style="color: #ff0000;"> <a href="http://www.bundoransurfco.com/webcam/"><strong>CLICK HERE FOR LIVE PEAK WEBCAM</strong></a></span></p>
<p>Low Tide: 1134 0.6m</p>
<p><b>3 day forecast to March 7th</b></p>
<p>Good swell all week but the winds are changing. Keep in an eye for gaps in the wind.</p>

        <style type='text/css'>
            #gallery-1 {
                margin: auto;
            }
            #gallery-1 .gallery-item {
                float: left;
                margin-top: 10px;
                text-align: center;
                width: 50%;
            }
            #gallery-1 img {
                border: 2px solid #cfcfcf;
            }
            #gallery-1 .gallery-caption {
                margin-left: 0;
            }
            /* see gallery_shortcode() in wp-includes/media.php */
        </style>
        <div id='gallery-1' class='gallery galleryid-113 gallery-columns-2 gallery-size-medium'><dl class='gallery-item'>
            <dt class='gallery-icon portrait'>
                <a href='http://www.bundoransurfco.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/11014854_10152577025667000_5213326955989933628_n.jpg'><img width="225" height="300" src="http://www.bundoransurfco.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/11014854_10152577025667000_5213326955989933628_n-225x300.jpg" class="attachment-medium colorbox-113 " alt="11014854_10152577025667000_5213326955989933628_n" /></a>
            </dt></dl>
            <br style='clear: both' />
        </div>

<p><a href="http://www.bundoransurfco.com/webcam/"> </a></p>
<h1> Wind Charts</h1>
<p><a href="http://www.windguru.cz/int/index.php?sc=103244"><img class="size-thumbnail wp-image-747 alignleft" title="wind guru" src="http://www.bundoransurfco.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/12/wind-guru-67x68.jpg" alt="" width="67" height="68" /></a> <a href="http://www.xcweather.co.uk/"><img class="alignnone size-thumbnail wp-image-749" title="xcweathersmall" src="http://www.bundoransurfco.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/12/xcweathersmall2-67x68.jpg" alt="" width="67" height="68" /></a>       <a href="http://www.buoyweather.com/wxnav6.jsp?region=UK&program=nww3BW1&grb=nww3&latitude=55.0&longitude=-8.75&zone=0&units=e"><img class="alignnone size-thumbnail wp-image-750" title="buoy weather" src="http://www.bundoransurfco.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/12/buoy-weather-67x68.jpg" alt="" width="67" height="68" /></a> <a href="http://www.windguru.cz/int/index.php?sc=103244">Wind Guru</a>       <a href="http://www.xcweather.co.uk/">XC Weather</a>       <a href="http://www.buoyweather.com/wxnav6.jsp?region=UK&program=nww3BW1&grb=nww3&latitude=55.0&longitude=-8.75&zone=0&units=e">Buoy Weather</a></p>
<h1>Swell Charts</h1>
<p><a href="http://magicseaweed.com/Bundoran-Surf-Report/50/"><img class="alignnone size-thumbnail wp-image-753" title="msw logo" src="http://www.bundoransurfco.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/12/msw-logo-67x43.jpg" alt="" width="75" height="43" /></a>             <a href="http://magicseaweed.com/UK-Ireland-MSW-Surf-Charts/1/"><img class="alignnone size-thumbnail wp-image-754" title="magicseaweedwamchart" src="http://www.bundoransurfco.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/12/magicseaweedwamchart1-67x68.png" alt="" width="67" height="68" /></a>       <a href="http://www.marine.ie/Home/site-area/data-services/marine-forecasts/wave-forecasts"><img class="alignnone wp-image-755 size-thumbnail" title="marine institute irish bouy data" src="http://www.bundoransurfco.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/12/marine-institute-irish-bouy-data-67x42.jpg" alt="" width="67" height="42" /></a>                 <a href="http://magicseaweed.com/Bundoran-Surf-Report/50/">Magic Seaweed</a>      <a href="http://magicseaweed.com/UK-Ireland-MSW-Surf-Charts/1/">MSM WAM</a>          <a href="http://www.marine.ie/Home/site-area/data-services/marine-forecasts/wave-forecasts">Marine Institute</a></p>
<h1>Pressure, Weather, Tides</h1>
<p><a href="http://news.bbc.co.uk/weather/forecast/13000"><img class="alignnone size-thumbnail wp-image-756" title="bbc pressure" src="http://www.bundoransurfco.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/12/bbc-pressure-67x68.jpg" alt="" width="67" height="68" /></a>          <a href="http://www.met.ie/"><img class="alignnone size-thumbnail wp-image-759" title="met eireann" src="http://www.bundoransurfco.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/12/met-eireann-67x68.jpg" alt="" width="67" height="68" /></a>            <a href="http://news.bbc.co.uk/weather/forecast/13000">BBC Pressure</a>      <a href="http://www.met.ie/">Met Eireann</a>      <a href="http://www.irishtimes.com/weather/tides.html">Irish Tide Tables</a></p>
```

This make my app crash : `'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Unable to parse the format string "SELF beginswith[c] '<a href='http://www.bundoransurfco.com/wp-content/uploads/'"'`

[image: ArrayBDD]

So how can I make my NSPredicate work ?

Comment: What kind of object are in `arrayBDD`?

Comment: @Larme Yeah sorry, I haven't mentioned that, EDITED ;)

Comment: @Larme no ideas ? :(

Comment: Your array BDD contains only one string? Plus, your string in the predicate has a "'" instead of a \" for the href.

Comment: @Larme I've edited again, for showing you what is in [[dicoBDD objectForKey:@"post"] objectForKey:@"content"] and what I've to fetch.

Comment: `@"SELF beginswith[c] %@", @"<a href='http://www.bundoransurfco.com/wp-content/uploads/"`?

Comment: @Larme I've tested like that : NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF beginswith[c] %@", @"<a href='http://www.bundoransurfco.com/wp-content/uploads/"]; and it doesn't work :/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72405/discussion-between-viny76-and-larme).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Unable to parse the format string "SELF beginswith[c] '<a href='http://www.bundoransurfco.com/wp-content/uploads/'"'
```

The issue appears because of the `'` in the `NSString` to search. That's why you have to use:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF beginswith[c] %@", @"<a href='bundoransurfco.com/wp-content/uploads/"];
```

This predicate (working) leads to another issue:

```
reason: '-[__NSCFString filteredArrayUsingPredicate:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

This means that in fact `arrayBDD` (`[[dicoBDD objectForKey:@"post"] objectForKey:@"content"]`) is a `NSString` and not a `NSArray`.
You've misunderstood the structure of your JSON.

So:

```
NSString *contentString = [[dicoBDD objectForKey:@"post"] objectForKey:@"content"];
```

Since you want to know how many times the `<a href='http://www.bundoransurfco.com/wp-content/uploads/` appears, I'd recommend this question [Number of occurrences of a substring in an NSString?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2166809/number-of-occurrences-of-a-substring-in-an-nsstring).
To get a replica of "arrayPictures" like, you could look at this question:
[Using NSRegularExpression to extract URLs on the iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9587458/using-nsregularexpression-to-extract-urls-on-the-iphone) and modify the pattern to fit your particular needs.