# iOS: UIWebView display link from website

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview

I have a UIWebView in my app that displays a website.  This website is not mobile friendly and is not hosted by me.  The only reason I am taking users to this website is to see a video.  The link to the video changes often, but the location of the video in the webpage remains the same. Essentially, I want to strip a link from someone else's webpage and use it in the UIWebView.  Is there a way to only display the video in the UIWebView if I do not know the url to the video?

Please don't hesitate to ask if you do not understand my question, thanks!

Comment: A way you could do this is to always have the UIWebView zoom in onto the video's location and disable the scrollview so the user cannot look at anything but the video. Is the app associated with the website or no?

Comment: The app is not associated with the website, how would I go about zooming in on the content?

Comment: You can extract links from the web page and find one which is associated with video , checkout this to extract all links http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9587458/using-nsregularexpression-to-extract-urls-on-the-iphone

Comment: Hi @MSU_Bulldog , if C_X's link doesn't help, let me know and I can post some zoom in code that might possibly help you...

Comment: Ok, thanks!  I am going to try C_X's suggestion since it is more of what I needed, but if that doesn't work for me I will be sure to let you know.