# Displaying string as link in UIWebview - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview

I have a string like this,

> var str = "Hello, go to http://stackoverflow.com"

and I want to display this string in a UIWebView, so that `http://stackoverflow.com` will be displayed as a link.

To do this, I am using `loadHtmlString` of UIWebView.

But the text is not displayed as a link. It is displayed as a normal text in UIWebView.

After some research, I found that the issue is `missing of <a href = ""></a> tag`.

For a static string, I can manually add the tags to the string. But I am getting the string from a http response. So I have no idea how to add the `<a>` tags in appropriate indices.

Is there any way I could parse and display the text as a link in UIWebView?

Comment: Is it required that the string is displayed in a `UIWebView`? You could display it in a `UITextView` with editing disabled and link detection enabled

Comment: Yes.. Because I am displaying images also.

Comment: @DeepikaMasilamani Then I recommend using regular expressions (`NSRegularExpression`) and replacing the matched strings with the string wrapped by the `<a>` tag

Comment: Take a look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9587458/using-nsregularexpression-to-extract-urls-on-the-iphone

Comment: Thanks for you suggestion. Can I get any sample code to use NSRegularExpression? I am not used to `NSRegularExpression`. That is why, If I get any links to learn about it, then it would be helpful to me.

Comment: Thank you so much @AlexanderNorth for suggesting me a link. I will definitely take a look at it.

Comment: Tell the server team to deliver the response string having `href` tag. Editing the content may be become a messy..

Comment: okay @NSPratik.. will definitely consider your suggestion. Thank you.

Comment: @DeepikaMasilamani I can write some sample code in a few minutes if that would help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set the [dataDetectorTypes](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIWebView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIWebView/dataDetectorTypes) to Link on the UIWebView. Here is an example you can run and view in a playground:

```
import UIKit
import XCPlayground

let str = "Hello, go to http://stackoverflow.com"
let webview = UIWebView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200.0, height: 200.0))
webview.dataDetectorTypes = .Link
webview.loadHTMLString(str, baseURL: nil)

XCPlaygroundPage.currentPage.liveView = webview
```

If your content does not rely on any HTML features and you are just tyring to display links then you should use a [UITextView](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextView_Class/) which also supports `dataDetectorTypes`.

Comment: I am displaying images also.. So I cannot use UITextView.

Comment: Helpful answer - upvoted, I have favorited this for later use. Thanks Joe

Answer (score 2):

@Joe's answer also looks good, here is another solution

```
let str = "Hello, go to http://stackoverflow.com or to http://example.com "

let detector = try! NSDataDetector(types: NSTextCheckingType.Link.rawValue)

let matches = detector.matchesInString(str, options: [], range: NSMakeRange(0, str.characters.count))

var newStr = str
for match in matches {
    let url = (str as NSString).substringWithRange(match.range)
    newStr = newStr.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(url, withString: "<a href='\(url)'>\(url)</a>")

}

print(newStr)
```

This modifies the string, to then be used in the `UIWebView`

Comment: Thanks a lot for this solution. I will try with this one too, to learn about NSDataDetector.